# Contenteditable HTML aganist an XML file that was loaded by xsl

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, xml, xslt

I followed this [link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/saving-contenteditable-content-changes-as-json-with-ajax/) to learn about how to save cotenteditable element into xml and further tried the live demo in [here](http://jsbin.com/owavu3). I tried incorporate this strategy into my current work but so far I can't get it to work.

Brief Summary of what I need to achieve:

1) Load an xml file from xsl that formats the data into HTML table (using sample xml and xsl from the tutorial on W3School on XML and XSL).

**DONE.**

2) In the HTML table I put the contenteditable attribute and make every field in the table editable. For example:

```
 <td><div contenteditable="true"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></div></td>
```

**DONE.**

3) Now I used the reference code that I followed with "saving the content from contenteditable" and attempted to save the content back to the XML file.

```
                    data[el.getAttribute('data-name')] = el.innerHTML;

                // send ajax to update the field
                $.ajax({
                   url: window.location.toString(),
                   data: data,
                   type: 'post'
                });
```

**UNDONE.**

Am I missing something with this ajax request? My xml file remains the same after I refresh the page.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What’s the response to the AJAX request? Look in your browser’s developer tools to see what happens. That tutorial doesn’t cover the server-side part of the problem, where you need software to listen for your update and change the original document.

Comment: @BuckDoyle There's no response.... I think this is what the problem is. I don't know if AJAX is required to achieve this. Would there be a simpler way to write back the updated data to the XML file?

Comment: The XML is coming from the server, the server needs to do the updating. It’s unfortunate that tutorial didn’t make clear that the client side editing is useless without a server-side persistence solution.